# why are these C / Cython arrays defined as character, not integer arrays?

Tags: python, c, cython

in an effort to solve question [#3367795](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367795/how-to-convert-python-cython-unicode-string-to-array-of-long-integers-to-do-leve) here on SO i have to cope with a number of subproblems. one of these is: in said algorithm (levenshtein distance), several arrays are allocated in memory and initialized with the lines

```
cdef char   *m1     = <char *>calloc(   blen + 2,    sizeof( char ) )
cdef char   *m2     = <char *>calloc(   blen + 2,    sizeof( char ) )
cdef char   *m3     = <char *>malloc( ( blen + 2 ) * sizeof( char ) )
#.........................................................................
for i from 0 <= i <= blen:
  m2[ i ] = i
  <...snip...>
```

`blen` here refers to the length of a Python `bytes` variable. now as far as i understand the algorithm (see my original post for the full code) and as the code for the initialization of `m2` clearly shows, these arrays are meant to hold integer numbers, not characters, so one would think the correct allocations should look like

```
cdef int    *m3     = <int *>malloc( ( blen + 2 ) * sizeof( int ) )
```

and so on. can anyone with a background in C elucidate to me why `char` is used? also, maybe more for people inclined to Cython, why is there a cast `<char *>`? one would think that `char *x = malloc( ... )` should suffice to define `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, to save memory -- but please note carefully that declaring these arrays as `char` limits the result distance to either 127 or 255, depending on whether the C compiler defaults to `signed char` or `unsigned char` respectively. In C, `char` is an integer type -- you don't need an `ord()` to get its integer value.

Your original code contains no mention of this limitation. **Note that if a `char` overflows, it does so silently and the code will produce incorrect results** -- 127 + 1 -> -128 (signed); 255 + 1 -> 0 (unsigned).

You didn't respond to my comment on your original question: """What are the (a) maximum (b) average sizes of your strings? Do you really need to do the whole O(M*N) thing if the two strings are nothing like each other?""" ..... Please answer that now (edit your question); had you done so then, you would have had this question answered then.

Update: Reading the original post again, I've noticed a problem: The code that reads

```
m1, m2 = m2, m1
strcpy( m3, m2 )
```

is WRONG on three grounds: (1) it doesn't shuffle the rows properly (should do `strcpy()` before swapping `m1` and `m2`) (2) `strcpy()` will not copy anything beyond the first null (zero byte) (3) there is no need to copy anything, just shuffle the pointers

```
m3, m2, m1 = m2, m1, m3
```

Comment: thx; your comment is not visible to me. i have added an edit to answer this point.

Comment: @flow: It IS visible to you (1) at the end of the comments you will see "show 1 more comment" (2) you would have been notified of a new comment by the little envelope icon at the top of the page next to your name being highlited

Comment: @flow: What precisely am I right about? What is so subtle? Are you talking about SO's comment visibility or the strcpy error or both?

Comment: i meant the half-greyed smallish "show 1 more comment" is 'subtle'. thx for your code fixes, i already incorporated them. right now running tests to see whether that gives correct results.

Answer (score 8):

Despite the misleading name, `char` types in C language are ordinary *integral* types, just like `short`, `int`, `long` and such. Of all integral types, `char`s have the smallest range and occupy the smallest amount of memory. So, if in your application it is important to save as much memory as possible, it might make sense to use `char` instead of `int`.

On some hardware platforms it might turn out that `int` types work faster than `char` types, so the selection of the specific type becomes a speed-vs-memory trade-off, but, once again, in many cases when the range of `char` is naturally sufficient, it might make more sense to use `char` instead of `int`.

Comment: Just a minor side note: C99's int_fast8_t type (and derivatives) leaves the mentioned speed vs. size trade-off to the implementation. Usually it gives you the fastest type with a minimum of 8 bits (one byte on most systems, i.e. a 'char') available.

Comment: at least *if* this is meant as a small integer one should never, never ever use `char` as the type, since its signedness is undefined and might vary from platform to platform. Use `signed char`, `unsigned char` or better the mentioned `int_fast8_t` or `int8_T` etc.